# Read https://google.com doesn't work anymore in Red?

Tags: red

Weird, Read https://google.com had been working, and today it doesn't work anymore:

> > read https://google.com
> >     *** Access Error: invalid UTF-8 encoding: #{E9206E27}

Comment: If something is clearly (or likely) transient, the value over time of putting it on StackOverflow as "institutional knowledge" is low.  It is probably a fit [for a bug tracker](https://github.com/red/red/issues) or just to go ask about it in [Red's chat rooms](https://gitter.im/red/home).  Remember that the "long tail" of value of StackOverflow isn't for the questioner: it's whether that question is likely to be useful for future users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a long time known issue with pages with invalid / different utf implementations.
This can help

```
convert-invalid: function [page] [
    collect/into [foreach c page [keep to-char c]]  clear ""
]

>> convert-invalid read/binary https://google.com
== {<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Web...
```

Comment: It DID work so it's not such long time issue. Google must have changed something. On some sites also.