# Read doesn't work with Wordpress.com pages

Tags: rebol, red

This is not the same question as  [Read https://google.com doesn't work anymore in Red?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47108274/read-https-google-com-doesnt-work-anymore-in-red)

Even with the fix above, it doesn't work:

```
convert-invalid: function [page] [
    collect/into [foreach c page [keep to-char c]]  clear ""
]

convert-invalid read/binary https://en.blog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/wordpress-for-ios-new-visual-editor-and-more/

  02/26/wordpress-for-ios-new-visual-editor-and-more/
  *** Access Error: cannot connect: https://en.blog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/wordpress-for-ios-new-visual-editor-and-more/ reason: timeout
  *** Where: read
  *** Stack: print convert-invalid
```

I check with Rebol, it works:

```
    >> read https://en.blog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/wordpress-for-ios-new-vi
    sual-editor-and-more/
    connecting to: en.blog.wordpress.com
    == {<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" data-placeholder-foc
    us="false"><head profile="http://gmpg....
    >>
```

Comment: @HostileFork previous question did work for https://google.com this is another problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely due to more widespread adoption of TLS 1.2, which none of the redbols currently support natively.

I just got slammed by this last week too. I have about 20 encapped local apps which allows users to easily query a dense Web API. In order to get these working again, I'd need to install cURL on all local machines. Yuck! :(

I have been successful in getting cURL to work with my code, although it is a little slower than I expected. See the other question here which covers the basics:

[Call curl from rebol or red](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041154/call-curl-from-rebol-or-red-doesnt-work?noredirect=1&lq=1)

(I've had the most difficulty getting Rebol3 Alpha to work with cURL, but I may just need more tinkering.)

Comment: Red does support TLS 1.2, as long as your operating system supports it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a different issue. Check your error message.

`Access Error: cannot connect: https:...`

Remedy: either wait for native **i/o** or [use **curl**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47041154/call-curl-from-rebol-or-red-doesnt-work)

Comment: I don't understand https://google.com is HTTPS and it works ? so why do you say Red doesn't support https.

Comment: Sorry, too fast and wrong explanation. There are a few roadblocks in **Red** especially regarding **I/O**

Answer (score 1):

That URL can be read from Red without any trouble:

```
--== Red 0.6.3 ==--
Type HELP for starting information.

>> read https://en.blog.wordpress.com/2015/02/26/wordpress-for-ios-new-visual-editor-and-more/
== {<!DOCTYPE html>^/<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" data-placeho
```

Red relies on the operating system networking layer for HTTPS, so it does not have the obsolescence issues of Rebol2.

My guess about your issue is that you are using a proxy to access the Internet, and Red does not support proxies yet (while Rebol does), so that would explain the timeout you get on connecting.